# Array indexing and counter overflow

Tags: c, embedded

i am having a counter which measures the strokes. I have allocated 3 bytes in a microcontroller means I have count upto 16777216. i want to maintain the count but as my count goes beyond 255 the LSB of array gets reset to zero and i am stuck how to increment to next array element by incrementing the count

I have tried

```
 Counterarray[strokelsb] = strokecount;
if(strokecount > 255)
  Counterarray[strokemid] = strokecount |Counterarray[strokelsb] ;


  Counterarray[strokelsb] = strokecount;
if(strokecount > 255)
  Counterarray[strokemid] = strokecount |Counterarray[strokelsb] ;
```

Expected result

```
Counterarray[strokelsb] = oxFF
 Counterarray[strokemid] + Counterarray[strokelsb] = 4095
```

Comment: Your two attempts look identical. Why would you include the low byte in the middle byte with `strokecount | Counterarray[strokelsb]`?

Comment: what is the type of the variable `strokecount`?

Comment: @Rishikesh Raje  strokecount is of static uint16_t type

Comment: @lurker I want to increment the count. thats why i copied there.

Comment: But none of the content of the low byte belongs to the middle byte. Also, separately, you say in your question your counter is 0 to 16777215, but you say in the comment that `strokecount` is a `uint16_t` type whose maximum value is 32767. That's a little confusing. Can you clarify?

Comment: Why not using a 32bit integer and masking the lower 24 bits? Or a bit field `struct{ uint32_t theNumber:24;}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what is the variable `strokecount` and what is the type of this variable. You do not need this variable to have a 3 byte counter.

The counter below will count from 0 to 16777215 and roll over.

```
if (//counter logic for one tick over)
{
    Counterarray[strokelsb]++;
    if (Counterarray[strokelsb] == 0x00)
    {
        Counterarray[strokemid]++;
        if (Counterarray[strokemid] == 0x00)
        {
            Counterarray[strokemsb]++;
        }
    }
}
```